# YUM reinstall original files from the package

Tags: centos, yum

I'm trying to reinstall a package on CentOS: `yum reinstall packagename` however I can still see the changes that I made in the config files from this package.

Is there a way to force the re-load of the package and its config files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check to see whether the reinstall of the package also created the config files with filenames ending with "**.rpmnew**". If such files exist, they will be the unmodified versions of the files.

If that is not the case, can you perform the package reinstallation in the two steps instead of one? That is, first do `yum remove packagename` and then do `yum install packagename`.

If neither of the above will do the trick, the simplest way to solve the problem is to rename or remove the config files and then do the yum reinstall.